# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'get' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I am trying to use either the email or username of the User class to login.  However, when I query for the email and try to do

```
object.get("username")
```

I get the error message above.  Strangely, when I test the helper function getUsername in the debugger it works fine

```
function getUsername(email) {
  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  query.equalTo('email', email);
  query.first({
    success: function(object) {
      console.log(object.get("username"));
      return object.get("username");
    },
    error: function(user, error) {
      console.log("no email");
    }
  });
}


function signIn(usernameOrEmail, password) {

  //if not email sign in with username
  if (usernameOrEmail.indexOf("@") == -1) {
    Parse.User.logIn(usernameOrEmail, password, {
      success: function(user) {
        console.log("Logged in!");
      },
      error: function(user, error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
    });
  }
  //query for username from email and signin
  else {
    var username = getUsername(usernameOrEmail);
    Parse.User.logIn(username, password, {
      success: function(user) {
        console.log("Logged in!");
      },
      error: function(user, error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: `getUsername` doesn't return anything. The `return` statement is in an asynchronous callback function.

Comment: if i dont return anything how do i set username  = getUsername(email)?

Comment: You need to pass a callback function to `getUsername`, and it should call it in the success function.

Comment: could i just put the query inside the signIn function? I do not know how callback functions work

Comment: All the functions you have after `success:` are callback functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`query.first` is an asynchronous function. To use the values it returns, you have to do it in the `success:` callback function. So pass a callbak to `getUsername` that performs the login.

```
function getUsername(email, callback) {
  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  query.equalTo('email', email);
  query.first({
    success: function(object) {
      if (object) {
        console.log(object.get("username"));
        callback(object.get("username"));
      } else {
        console.log("email not found");
      }
    },
    error: function(user, error) {
      console.log("no email");
    }
  });
}

function signIn(usernameOrEmail, password) {

  //if not email sign in with username
  if (usernameOrEmail.indexOf("@") == -1) {
    Parse.User.logIn(usernameOrEmail, password, {
      success: function(user) {
        console.log("Logged in!");
      },
      error: function(user, error) {
        alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
      }
    });
  }
  //query for username from email and signin
  else {
    getUsername(usernameOrEmail, function(username) {
        signIn(username, password);
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: unfortunately I'm still getting an error when I replace your code with mine, saying that signIn is not defined.  Thanks for everything so far any additional help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Check for typos, because I don't see why that would happen. The scope of a function name includes its function body.

Comment: Do you have a public URL I could try?

Comment: No I don't have a public URL I will just look for typos then. Thankyou!

Comment: the error is in the last line its says unexpected identifier

Comment: Left out the `{`, sorry

Comment: sorry to keep bothering you but now I'm getting an error in the object.get("username") line saying cannot read property 'get' of undefined

Comment: You need to check whether the query found a matching row. If not, `object` will be `undefined`. I've added that check.